# Php file path problems

Tags: php, file, path

I am having issues with this piece of code. I have set the file path as 'uploads/' but it is not succeeding. I'm not getting a success message or the failed message. I'm new to PHP so probably making a really simple error. Thanks.

```
<?php
$name = $_FILES['video']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['video']['size'];
$type = $_FILES['video']['type'];

$tmp_name = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];

if(isset($name)){
    if(!empty($name)){

        $location = 'uploads/';

        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
            echo 'Success!';
        }
    }
    }else{
        echo 'Failed';
}
?>
```

Comment: where's the html for this?

Comment: btw, `if(isset($name)){
    if(!empty($name)){` is redundant. The latter is good enough.

Comment: You're only checking the result of `move_uploaded_file()` for a success, not a failure. If you put an `else` on that `if`, you'll likely find your problem.

Comment: Make sure you have permissions in the path 'uploads/'. Btw,  where is 'uploads/' on your server? (Seems like relative to your script location?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 $name = $_FILES['video']['name'];
 $video_tmp = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];


if(isset($name)){
if(!empty($name)){

    move_uploaded_file($video_tmp,”video/my_videos/$name”);//change video/my_videos to the correct path where you'll like to store them
   echo "success";
     }
}else{
    echo 'Failed';
 }
```

Comment: Have tried this, thank you. I'm getting my error messages as required but still not working. Getting this in the error logs on the server. 

[php7:warn] [pid 16701] [client ::1:53851] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/private/var/tmp/php9gBz8W' to 'uploads/1167682_660528143959546_2020930120_o.jpg' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/home/upload.php on line 11, referer: http://localhost/home/profile.php

Comment: go to your folder location where you'lld like to store the videos. check the folder properties. make sure you allow read and write for all users